# Is there a way to know if your coroutine has been canceled from within a suspend function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, android-workmanager

I'm using a CoroutineWorker but all my business logic is a separate class which I start using a suspend function. I would prefer to keep all the logic in this class but I need to know if the work request has been canceled. Is there someway to know in the suspend function if it's been canceled?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If your suspend function is async it will be canceled immediately

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether the current `Job` is still active (has not completed and was not cancelled yet) in the `suspend` function you can use [`isActive`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/is-active.html) property. Example:

```
suspend fun callApi() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    //...

    if (!isActive) {
        // coroutine is not active
    }
}
```

Another common way to check for cancellation is to call [`ensureActive()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/ensure-active.html?query=fun%20CoroutineContext.ensureActive()), which is an extension function available for `Job`, `CoroutineScope`, and `CoroutineContext`. Example:

```
suspend fun callApi() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    //...

    ensureActive() // it throws a CancellationException and will stop the execution
}
```

Comment: Plain `suspend` function (without `withContext`) doesn't provide `isActive` flag, but you can use `coroutineContext.isActive`

Answer (score 1):

Repeating gmk57's answer:

"Plain `suspend` function (without `withContext`) doesn't provide `isActive` flag, but you can use `coroutineContext.isActive`"

With a suspend function you do have access to your `corountineContext`. Accessing that will give you access to all of the same properties that you can access from directly inside the context.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either

```kotlin
coroutineScope { ensureActive() }
```

```kotlin
yield() // If this CPU heavy computation job.
```