# How to cancel withContext in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I have one function inside that I am trigger an event at particular time.

```
fun startTimeWarning() {
     viewModelScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            if (!isActive) {
                delay(2000)
                // trigger event
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Now I want to trigger new event in `cancelTimeWarning` and make sure `startTimeWarning` is not active. Is it possible to cancel in `withContext`?

```
fun cancelTimeWarning() {
     viewModelScope.launch {
           // new event trigger
     }
}
```

I checked in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70783900/11560810) but I don't think this will help me. Many thanks

UDPATE

After @Tenfour04 suggestion I am adding my JOB code below

```
class PairViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    internal var timeJob = Job()
        get() {
            if (field.isCancelled) field = Job()
            return field
        }

    fun handleTimeWarning(index: Int) {
        if (index == -1) {
            startTime()
        } else {
            cancelTime()
        }
    }

    internal fun startTime() {
        viewModelScope.launch(timeJob) {
            delay(2000)
            UIEvent(UIevent.XYZ)
        }
    }

    internal fun cancelTime() {
        if (timeJob.isActive) {
            timeJob.cancel()
        }
        UIEvent(UIevent.ABC)
    }
}
```

Comment: `viewModelScope.launch` will return a Coroutine's `Job`, which you can use to cancel this job.

Comment: @SovathnaHong I don't want to use Job.

Comment: @vivekmodi What do you mean "I don't want to use Job"? Any specific reason for this?

Comment: Actually I tried before and it works. My supervisor told to use with `withContext` and remove `Job` to avoid with extra code. If you want I can share code above.. Many thanks @m0skit0

Comment: You cannot cancel a Coroutine Job manually without introducing an extra variable.

Comment: Sure, thanks a million. I'll accept your answer..

Comment: @SovathnaHong when we cancel can we check that `timeWarningContex` is Active or not ?

Comment: I think we need more information to understand the actual problem. Either your supervisor doesn’t understand what they’re talking about, or there is a different approach to what you’re doing. What are the exact conditions under which you want this inner piece of the coroutine to be cancelled?

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04. Thanks for replying. I'll explain my scenario. I have logic to trigger event after some delay. I think delay only works with suspend function. So I didn't make a function to be suspended and I used viewmodelscope for this.

Comment: My goal is to cancel that delay in specific conditions and trigger new event

Comment: I tried with job and it was working fine. But I was added new variable in my file and supervisor told me not to use Job instead of withContext.

Comment: @Tenfour04 my main goal is to delay and trigger some A event. When trigger B event I need to check Trigger A is not active. If A is active then cancel and trigger B event.

Comment: I still don't understand clearly enough to answer. Maybe you can show your code with the Job that did work so we can understand exactly what the behavior should be. Because I can't think of how you can trigger something from an arbitrary function without having some property somewhere (in your case a Job) to accept the instruction to trigger something.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have added code snippet what code looks like..

Comment: Is `cancelTime()` called under any arbitrary event, or is it called only after a certain amount of time has passed? The only way I can possibly think of a better way to do it than your original Job code is if thetime when `cancelTime()` will be called can be predicted when `startTime()` is called.

Comment: @Tenfour04 what is `arbitrary event` means?

Comment: Like could it be called in response to a variety of reasons like the user clicking something. Do you always know ahead of time exactly when it will be called?

Comment: Yes when user click on button I will start trigger `startTime` and when user click on list i'll trigger `cancelTime`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that you want to use `Job` or not. The `viewModelScope.launch` will return a Coroutine Job, so that you can use this reference to cancel it manually in your case.

```
private var timeWarningJob: Job? = null
...
fun startTimeWarning() {
     timeWarningJob = viewModelScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            if (!isActive) {
                delay(2000)
                // trigger event
            }
        }
     }
}

fun cancelTimeWarning() {
    timeWarningJob?.cancel() // Cancel your last job
    viewModelScope.launch {
          // new event trigger
    }
}
```

Comment: So inside `cancelTimeWarning` when `timeWarningContext` is not active and when we trying to cancel the context then it will not cause any expection?

Comment: Your approach to cancelling the context will not work.  Cancelling `timeWarningContext` will have no effect.

Comment: Sorry @LouisWasserman I didn't get it.

Comment: You are saying if I used 
`if (timeWarningContext.isActive)  {
    timeWarningContext.cancel()
    }` it will not work ?

Comment: You can’t cancel a CoroutineContext. And if you could, this would be cancelling all of Dispatchers.Default, which would be pretty catastrophic if it was allowed.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of CoroutineScope. If you cancel a CoroutineScope, it cancels its children jobs. But this wouldn't satisfy the supervisor's expectation that a property be eliminated. It would just be trading the Job for a CoroutineScope that is the parent of that Job.

Comment: Yes, I am saying that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer with job canceling is correct. My answer is just an option to solve it by the other way.

You can create and use a new coroutine scope based on viewModelScope to handle it.

```
// SupervisorJob allows to cancel children without cancel the whole scope
private val startScope = CoroutineScope(lifecycleScope.coroutineContext + SupervisorJob())

fun startTimeWarning() {
    startScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            // You don't have to check isActive in async code, the delay will be canceled immediately at a job cancelation
            delay(2000)
            // trigger event
        }
    }
}

fun cancelTimeWarning() {
    // The following line will cancel ALL children coroutines of startScope
    // but will not cancel the start scope and you can reuse it to launch a new coroutine
    startScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
    viewModelScope.launch {
       // new event trigger
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

The next step: you can set Dispatchers.Default to the start scope:

```
private val startScope = CoroutineScope(lifecycleScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.Default + SupervisorJob())
```

Now you can remove withContext at startTimeWarning:

```
fun startTimeWarning() {
    startScope.launch {
        delay(2000)
        // trigger event
    }
}
```

Comment: If `startScope` is not active then we call `cancelTimeWarnig`  it will not thorw any exceptions?

Comment: @vivekmodi no it will not

Comment: Perfect.. thanks for giving me new option..